# VB.NET error message - "Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Object' to 'String'"

Tags: vb.net

I have an error in my [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET) program. I have tried various casts, etc., but it just will not resolve the issue - so reluctantly I post it here to see if anyone else has a similar problem.

#### Error message

> Error 1   Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Object' to 'String'.

#### Code

```
Private DS As New DataSet ' Languages
Function TransTxt(ByVal Frm As String, ByVal Item As String) As String

    Dim language As String
    Select Case My.Settings.Language
        Case 0 : language = "en" ' English
        Case 1 : language = "fr" ' French
        Case 2 : language = "it" ' Italian
        Case 3 : language = "sp" ' spanish
        Case 4 : language = "pt" ' portuguese
        Case 5 : language = "de" ' german
        Case 6 : language = "du" ' dutch
        Case Else : language = "en" ' English
    End Select


    Try 'ONE of these rows is the error
        Dim DR() As DataRow = DS.Tables(Frm).Select("Tag = '" & Item & "'")
        Return DR(0).Item(language) 
        Catch ex As Exception 
          Return "- error -" & Item
    End Try 
End Sub
```

Comment: A general hint for debugging: Remove the Try-Catch. Then Visual Studio will break in the line that really causes the error. In addition, you shouldn't return error messages as the return value of functions --- that's what Exceptions are for. Just let the (unexpected) Exception bubble up your function tree and only handle it at the very top level.

Comment: @Heinzi - this is a *compile* error.

Comment: @Hans: Uh.. of course, right, sorry about that. I guess the comment "`ONE of these rows is the error`" at the beginning of the try block and the fact that the OP didn't say in which line the error occurred made me read the question sloppily.

Answer (score 4):

`Return DR(0).Item(language)` is my guess.

Either `CAST` to a `STRING` type or use `Return DR(0).Item(language).ToString()` at the end.

Comment: I'd suggest to use the strongly typed `DR(0).Field(Of String)(language)`. If that's not available (.net < 3.5), I'd go for a cast using `DirectCast`: This documents clearly that we *know* that it's a string (and that we don't want a conversion to take place).